# How to reseolve this ninja error ? (W11/Clion)

Tags: c, clion

i recently got into C for my school and have this error o n Jetbrains with Windows 11 (latest build from both). A friend of mine does not have the error on the same program:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.3.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build "C:\Users\pablo\OneDrive\Bureau\MALAISE\info\C bebou\e\ProjectPart1\cmake-build-debug" --target ProjectPart1 -j 6
[1/1] Linking C executable ProjectPart1.exe
FAILED: ProjectPart1.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.1\bin\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -g  CMakeFiles/ProjectPart1.dir/main.c.obj CMakeFiles/ProjectPart1.dir/shapes.c.obj -o ProjectPart1.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libProjectPart1.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.3.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/ProjectPart1.dir/shapes.c.obj:C:/Users/pablo/OneDrive/Bureau/MALAISE/info/C bebou/e/ProjectPart1/shapes.h:4: multiple definition of `global_id'; CMakeFiles/ProjectPart1.dir/main.c.obj:C:/Users/pablo/OneDrive/Bureau/MALAISE/info/C bebou/e/ProjectPart1/shapes.h:4: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Sorry if I put too much i'm no that great on C yet.
Thanks and have a great day

I tried updating windows, Clion, reinstalling in a different folder.

Comment: What is this ```global_id``` in your code?

Comment: it's to assign to a shape, my code goal is to make a paint with vectors in a without  a gui.

Comment: edit : i renamed it and it still does an error

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Comment: Did you define `global_id` in header `shapes.h` and do you include that header in multiple C files? (BTW: You should not definy functions or variables in headers at all! Only declare in headers and define in C files.) Or do you include that file twice and did not protect against multiple inclusion?

Comment: The error you get also depends on your compiler. For GCC, the default settings changed between versions. In older versions you could have `int a;` in multiple files as long as you did not initialize. With more recent versions you will get the error message you see. But in any case that is bad code and you should fix it. First thing should be to check the code. Windows Updates will barely fix compilation errors.

Comment: Oh, and the question "what is global_id" could best be answered by showing how and where you define it. (Always better show it than describe it) A text description what you intent to do with it is very inprecise and does not help in finding any error.